# Azure Databricks scheduled jobs taking longer to respond

Tags: job-scheduling, azure-databricks

In Azure DataBricks i have scheduled one job with notebook attached to simple python file.

```
[![dbutils.widgets.text("input", "","")
dbutils.widgets.get("input")
y = getArgument("input")
print ("Param -\'input':")
print (y)][1]][1]
```

Cluster: D8s_v3 ( 1 Worker)

even though its quite simple code its take about 9 to 10 second to execute by DataBricks Jobs. If i run python file directly it execute under 1 second.

Please guide me to optimize it for DataBricks Jobs

[image]tg.png

Comment: This is just overhead of scheduling the job. I wouldn't expect it to run nearly as fast. Spark is a batch processing application. Why do you need such as fast response time? If you process significant volumes of data then scheduling overhead becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @simon_dmorias thanks for your inputs. I want to run Anamoly detection model using this Jobs and for that i want to execute this job every 1 sec passing real time data from sensor attached to device

Comment: Use databricks to train the model. But not for real-time api responses. Take the trained model and use something like azure functions to serve up results using the model.